# Number of terms in arithmetic series if we are given the sum of the series

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we are given value of $x$ such that
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^ni$$
How we can find $n$ according $x$?

I think
$\sqrt{2x}=\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ but at this state I get stuck to convert equality to something like $n=\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

We use the quadratic formula to solve this question.

The equation is $x=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$\Rightarrow n^2+n=2x$

$\Rightarrow n^2+n+\dfrac{1}{4}=2x+\dfrac{1}{4}$

$\Rightarrow \left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{8x+1}{4}$

$\Rightarrow n+\dfrac{1}{2}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$

$\Rightarrow n=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$

Since you want the number of terms, only $n=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{8x+1}}{2}$ is correct

Answer (score 0):

We have $x = n(n-1)/2 $

That means that : $2x = n^2 -n $

Therefore : $ n^2 -n - 2x = 0$

Then you can use the quadratic formula and solve it.

Which will give you : $ n = \frac{1+ \sqrt{(1+4x)}} {2} $

Comment: Note that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge 1$, we have $n<\sqrt{n(n+1)}<n+1$. So $n=\lfloor\sqrt{2x}\rfloor$. (Floor function of $\sqrt{2x}$ )